# Unhandled Exception when converting const char to char

Tags: c++, strcat

I've been trying to convert a const char to a char for the past 30 minutes.
Here's what I've got.

```
 string atr; 

 getline(cin,atr); // Start off with a string because getline takes nothing else.
 const char *buffA = atr.c_str(); // Create a const char of the string converted to a const char.
 char *buff = ""; // Create a new char to hold the converted result.
 strcat(buff,buffA); // Do the conversion.
 parseargs(buff); // Pass the data on.
```

However, I get an unhandled exception. I have no idea why. I literally just typed 'try' into the console as my only argument.

Comment: "I've been trying to convert a const char to a char" NO NO NO NO NO NO. Stop wanting this. Tell us what you are trying to do that you believe would be done by converting a const char to a char. Describe your problem, not merely your solution.

Comment: But why don't you just use the `string` directly ?

Comment: I recommend that you pick up [a good introductory C++ book (click on this link for a list)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) so you can learn some modern C++ techniques that would make your code much more understandable, concise, and safe. As you can see from [nightcracker's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18054812/308661), your code can be rewritten with less lines and actually work.

Comment: @Nbr44 You can't use 'getline' with a string, unfortunately.

Comment: @Daaksin: [The C++ standard library provides a version that works with `std::string`s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: @Daaksin but isn't that what you are already doing ? `getline(cin,atr);`. A string is bound to be easier to manipulate than a `char` array, too !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code.  First, you
initialize a `char*` with a string literal.  This uses
a deprecated convertion; the type of a string literal is `char
const[]` (which converts to `char const*`, not to `char*`),
because any attempt to modify the literal is undefined behavior.
The second is that your string literal is only one `char` long,
so even if you could write to it, unless `atr` was empty, you're
writing beyond the end of the buffer.

You don't tell us anything about `parseargs`.  If it doesn't
modify it's argument, you can just pass it `atr.c_str()`, and be
done with it.  (If it's a legacy function which ignores const,
you may have to use a `const_cast` here.)  If it does modify its
argument (say because it uses `strtok`), then you'll have to
explicitly push a `'\0'` onto the end of `atr`, and then pass it
`&atr[0]`.  (Not a particularly clean solution, but if you're
not using `atr` afterwards, it should work.)

Answer (score 8):

Try using C++ instead of C idioms:

```
std::vector<char> data(atr.begin(), atr.end());
data.push_back('\0');
parseargs(&data[0]);
```

Comment: Close.  As written, it's probably undefined behavior: since `parseargs` doesn't take a length, it almost certainly expects a `'\0'` terminated string.  So you need to push back a `'\0'` before passing `&data[0]`.  (Of course, if `parseargs` doesn't modify its argument, `atr.c_str()` solves the problem completely.  It's likely that there's no need for a copy anyway.)

Comment: Straight to the point! Thanks for the code snippet, nightcracker !

Answer (score 4):

Both your contents of `buff` and `buffA` are in read-only memory of the process.
You will actually need to `new` your `buff` like

```
char* buff = new char[32];
```

This provides memory from the free-store and you can then `strcat` the string from `buffA` to `buff`.
You should prefer `strncat`, though to avoid buffer-overruns and `delete` your `buff` eventually.

Comment: Oh! Right, thank you so much for this answer. I continually forget that in C++ you must assign memory to your variables. Well, anyway, cheers !

Comment: You are welcome, but please don't Forget to distinguish between heap and stack-based variables (consider, arrays, too)!!

Comment: @Daaksin On top of that, it would be a lot better if you just used a `string` instead of converting to `char*`in the first place.

Comment: You definitely don't want to use `strcat` on an uninitialized buffer.  And you don't want to use `strncat` if you expect to pass the pointer to function later.  If you know the maximum size, you don't want to use `new`; you should just use a local buffer.  And if you don't, `std::vector<char>` will do a better job at allocating and freeing the array (and will initialize it so that `strcat` won't be undefined behavior, although why `strcat`, and not `strcpy` beats me).

Answer (score 2):

This

```
char *buff = ""; // Create a new char to hold the converted result.
```

creates a `char *` that points to (probably read-only) memory of about 1 byte in extent. This:

```
 strcat(buff,buffA); // Do the conversion.
```

attempts to overwrite that (probably read-only) memory of 1 or so bytes with an arbitrary string.

The chances are this will promptly crash. If the memory is read only, it will crash immediately. If the memory is not read only it will stomp over random data, resulting in very undefined behaviour.

Why on earth do you want to do that? Does `parseArgs` actually need a modifiable string? It's *parsing* arguments, it shouldn't need to change them. If it's really necessary, use a `std::vector<char>` and pass the address of the first element and hope that all it does is poke the contents of the array, rather than (say) running over the end.